# Can I customise the 'not recognized as the name of a cmdlet' error in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, command-line, powershell-core

Say I make a typo on the command line:

```
whih foo
```

Powershell returns:

```
whih : The term 'whih' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ whih mocha
+ ~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (whih:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The long message is useful for scripts, but for interactive shell use, I'd like to wrap it with something shorter, like:

```
'whih' isn't a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

**Can I wrap the error and change it to something shorter?**

Comment: Have to ask but I will assume that a try block is not what (designed for this purpose) you want and you are looking to change the actual verbage of the message

Comment: @Matt That's correct, it's for interactive use as mentioned. So yes I don't want to wrap every command in a `try` block. Just looking for something for `$profile`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can intercept the `CommandNotFoundException` with [a `CommandNotFoundAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.commandinvocationintrinsics.commandnotfoundaction?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0)!

```
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.CommandNotFoundAction = {
  param($Name,[System.Management.Automation.CommandLookupEventArgs]$CommandLookupArgs)  

  # Check if command was directly invoked by user
  # For a command invoked by a running script, CommandOrigin would be `Internal`
  if($CommandLookupArgs.CommandOrigin -eq 'Runspace'){
    # Assign a new action scriptblock, close over $Name from this scope 
    $CommandLookupArgs.CommandScriptBlock = {
      Write-Warning "'$Name' isn't a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."
    }.GetNewClosure()
  }
}
```

Comment: That's way easier then what I was thinking of doing.

Comment: Proxying `Format-Default` or finding the language file/data associated to that message. I had no idea you could make a trigger like that.

Comment: @Matt ahh, that's both clever and terribly inadvisable :P

Comment: Indeed. However its the only option I could think off. Now I need to research what you have done here to see how else I can use it :)

Comment: @Matt hit me up on twitter (or gitter) if you need more inspiration ;)

Comment: Like it +1. Is `$Name` always automatically prepended with the verb `Get-` ?

Comment: @LotPings only when the search term is not in `Verb-Noun` form (the CommandDiscovery API errors out after trying _twice_, once as is, once with `Get-` prepended)

Comment: @LotPings PowerShell soft-aliases all commands without a verb as `Get-`.  You can observe this by typing `service` at the prompt.

Comment: Awesome answer and works perfectly. Why is `.GetNewClosure()` necessary? Thanks!

Comment: Also: this also effects ps1 scripts. Is there a way to have it only be invoked on interactive use?

Comment: @mikemaccana `.GetNewClosure()` is necessary to close over the `$Name` variable. Updated answer to address both of your questions

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen - accepted as an answer as it meets all the requirements!